# I'm trying to run this function to check if the database has the same email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eclipse

```
function runthis(){
        var email = $("#email").val();

          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            var url = serverURL() + "/Achecksameemail.php"; 
                url += "?email=" + email;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
            runthisResult(xmlhttp.responseText);
                 } 
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();   
        }


    function runthisResult(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);     
        for(var i=0; i < arr.length;i++){

            if(arr[i].email = $("#email").val()){
            alert("This email has already been used. Please use another email.");

        }

        else { 
            savenewuser();
        }
    }

}
```

However, when it checks that the email has not been used, it can't run the second function to save the user details to the database. Anyone know why? Thank You!

Comment: You are not comparing here `arr[i].email = $("#email").val()`. use `==`

Comment: Hmmm.. I've changed to arr[i].email == $("#email").val(), but after it checks that is not the same email it can't run the second function savenewuser();

Comment: You must check this on server not javascript. This is so wrong way !! dont do this at all

Comment: "/Achecksameemail.php" will retrieve all the email from the database and check if the email is the same as the current. Isn't it how it should be done? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Check email existing and validation in `Achecksameemail.php`

```
$response = [
    'exists' => TRUE,
    'msg'    => ''
];

if(filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '".$_GET['email']."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($select))
        $response['msg'] = 'This email is already being used';
    else
        $response['exists'] = FALSE; 
}
else
{
    $response['msg'] = 'Invalid email address!';
} 

echo json_encode($response);
```

And response in js

```
function runthisResult(response)
{
    response = JSON.parse(response);     

    if(response.exists)
        alert(response.msg);
    else
        savenewuser();
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Damon.s I've tried your code, but it will always prompt the error message 'Invalid email address' even though the database do not have the email. Thank you.

Comment: @joqi I edited this `if(!filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` to `if(filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` => `remove the "!"` and test it.

Comment: now it does not pop out the error message and it just run the savenewuser();

Comment: may i know where is the problem? Thank you:)